# DataGridViewCell - Change BackColor without losing focus

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with one column displaying color. The column contains DataGridViewTextBox type, which I leave blank and change the Style.BackColor.

When the user clicks on the cell, I open a ColorDialog and use the resulting color to set BackColor of the cell. However as noted in two similar questions ([DataGridViewCell not updating until change the focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51009332) and [DataGridViewCell Background Color Change Without Losing Focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433756)), the display will not change the BackColor until the cell loses focus, either from the user clicking elsewhere or the code executing DataGridView.CurrentCell.Selected=False

I would like to know: What is happening in .NET when the cell loses focus that allows it to be repainted and can I call that directly?

It does work to deselect the cell, but I would like to avoid that since I want to keep that row selected and also because I don't want to trigger any other events that I'm not intending to.

My code below (Note that during the grid refresh the selection highlighting is set to transparent for the CondColor column):

```
Private Sub RefreshCondGrid()
    DataGridConditions.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    Dim sql = "SELECT *, iif(BLCond='N','New',iif(BLCond='U','Used','')) BLCondName FROM Inventory.Condition_List;"
    DataGridConditions.DataSource = GetTable(sql)
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridConditions.Rows
        row.Cells("CondColor").Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.Transparent
        If row.DataBoundItem IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not IsDBNull(row.DataBoundItem("ColorInt")) Then
            row.Cells("CondColor").Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(row.DataBoundItem("ColorInt"))
        End If
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub DataGridConditions_CellContentClick(sender As DataGridView, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridConditions.CellClick
    If sender.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "CondColor" Then
        Dim item = sender.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem
        If Not IsDBNull(item("ColorInt")) Then
            ColorDialog1.Color = Color.FromArgb(item("ColorInt"))
        End If
        ColorDialog1.ShowDialog()
        item("ColorInt") = ColorDialog1.Color.ToArgb
        sender.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Style.BackColor = ColorDialog1.Color
    End If
End Sub
```

[image: Screenshot of DataGridView]
Note: the selection highlighting does *not* obscure the color cell in any way

Comment: I think the code works, but the color is hidden because the current cell has the highlight color.

Comment: Ah, normally that would be true, but I forgot to include that I removed the selection highlighting from that column for that reason. I'll add that to the code sample.

Comment: I am in agreement with LarsTech. Add this line of code to the end of the `CellContentClick` event… `DataGridConditions.Rows(e.RowIndex).Selected = False` and It should show the proper color. I am guessing the `Color.Tranparent` may not be so transparent.

Comment: So First, I specifically do not want to deselect the cell or the row, as stated. I'm trying to find out what happens when the row is deselected to repaint the cell so I can call it manually. Second, you can choose to believe me or not, but I promise you the selection highlighting does not cover the cell in any way. I'll add a screenshot to the question.

Comment: The `...Selected = False` from @JohnG seems to work fine.  It doesn't move the focus to a different control or cell.

Comment: You need to set the `SelectionBackColor` property to the same color. Just add right after the last line: `sender.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Style.SelectionBackColor = ColorDialog1.Color` and it should work. Do yourself a favor and `Option Strict On`.

Comment: dr.null your suggestion works! And John G was probably right when he said that Transparent may not be so transparent. I still don't understand *why* it works - the display color was the previous BackColor, not the Selected color or transparent. But it solves the problem and would be great to have it as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on the solution from [dr.null](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14171304/dr-null), there are multiple layers of drawing in a DataGridView.

The BackColor is underneath the SelectionBackColor (which appears only when a row is selected) and for most records, setting the BackColor to the desired color and the SelectionBackColor to transparent will display the desired BackColor.

However, when first drawing a DataGridView, one record is selected *before* the colors are set. And in .NET, the BackColor is not drawn at all if the record is already selected. It does not get drawn until after the record has been deselected.  Therefore setting the BackColor of the currently selected row to Color.Orange and the SelectedBackColor to Color.Transparent, will display whatever BackColor was previously set for that row.

Therefore to solve the issue, at least for the currently selected row, but good practice for all rows, is to set the SelectedBackColor to the desired color and not Transparent.

Just to reiterate - Color.Transparent works as expected - the problem is .NET failing to draw BackColor first.

Answer (score 1):

Try this… After the color has been set for the cells background, call the grids `EndEdit` then immediately call the grids `BeginEdit.` This should cause the grid to redraw and show the selected color immediately and keep it as the selected cell.

```
If sender.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "CondColor" Then
  Dim item = sender.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem
  If Not IsDBNull(item("ColorInt")) Then
    ColorDialog1.Color = Color.FromArgb(item("ColorInt"))
  End If
  ColorDialog1.ShowDialog()
  item("ColorInt") = ColorDialog1.Color.ToArgb
  sender.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Style.BackColor = ColorDialog1.Color
  DataGridConditions.EndEdit()
  DataGridConditions.BeginEdit(False)
End If
```

Also, as an aside, the posted code will only work if the compiler `Option strict` is set to `OFF.` It is good practice to turn this option on. Unfortunately, the current code is going to throw a few errors if it is turned on. Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks, but that did not work. It did call the DataGridView.Paint event, but the cell did not change color until it was deselected. Something else is happening, maybe int he SelectionChanged event, that causes it to be new BackColor value to be painted correctly

Comment: I am using the same code you posted, added the two lines as shown and it works on my end. I am not sure how the `SelectionChanged` event would affect this, the selection is not changing.

Comment: I hope you are aware that calling `RefreshCondGrid` is going to clear any of the cell coloring unless the color is saved to the DB.

Comment: Understood - that is only called when the form is opened. And ultimately the color will be saved to the DB but in testing it's useful to leave that out for now